# Using Paste to get the input data from the checkboxGroupInput aggregated and seperated by comma

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the below code to get the input from checkboxGroupInput to aggregate and separated by comma so that i can use them in my further query as an input.

I tried the below code but this is not working and giving me error.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    checkboxGroupInput(inputId="variable", label="OG to show:", 
                       choiceNames=c("All","CMT","FS","HPS","PRD","RES"),
                       choiceValues=c("All","CMT","FS","HPS","PRD","RES"),
                       selected = NULL,
                       inline = T
                       #, multiple = T,selectize = T),
    )),  

    dashboardBody(  

      textOutput('table1')      

    ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  OG <- reactive({
    switch(input$variable,
           "All" = 1,
           "CMT" = 2,
           "FS" = 3,
           "HPS" = 4,
           "PRD" = 5,
           "RES" = 6)
  })

 OG1 <- reactive({icons1 <- paste(OG(), collapse = ",")})

 output$table1 <-renderText({OG1()})

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Expected Output is 2,3,....
As per the selection from checkbox it should give me the # separated by comma.

Comment: You have `selected = NULL`  try with one value `selected = "CMT"` and also if there are none selected, you can have `req`

Comment: can you confirm it works for you @JK1185?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `req()` and `sapply()` to solve the issues.

To avoid using `NULL` if no option is selected use `req()`. In order to pass an vector of inputs to `switch()` you can use `sapply()`.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "variable", label = "OG to show:", 
                       choiceNames = c("All","CMT","FS","HPS","PRD","RES"),
                       choiceValues = c("All","CMT","FS","HPS","PRD","RES"),
                       selected = NULL, inline = T
    )
  ),  

  dashboardBody(  
    textOutput('table1')      
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  OG <- reactive({
    req(input$variable)
    unname(sapply(input$variable, switch,
           "All" = 1, "CMT" = 2, "FS" = 3, "HPS" = 4, "PRD" = 5, "RES" = 6))
  })

  output$table1 <-renderText({
    print(OG() %in% 2:6)
  })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: Thank you for the above explanation it is working. But I want to store the above input as c(2,3,....0) and used it under subset with a if condition. KK1 <- reactive({BB1 <- if((XX() != "") && (OG() %in% c(2:6)) && (Region() %in% c(2:5)) && (RBE() %in% c(2:7))){subset(dataInput(),((OGNum %in% c(OG1()))))}}). In the above query i am using it in {subset(dataInput(),((OGNum %in% c(OG1()))))} where c(OG1()) is the filter condition.

Comment: Ok, not sure I understand it correctly. From your question I understand you want to concentenate per comma. Do I understand your comment correctly you want a vector of the numbers you get from the switch function?

Comment: Thnk you for your response. Yes correct i want it in a vector format under a function e.g OG1 which i can call inside subset function to do my further actions. Actually i have a dataframe name dataInput() which i am filtering using the parameters in OG1. Thank you.

Comment: see my edit. `OG()` will output a vector now. In `renderText()` one of the tests is shown. An upvote is appreciated :).